# SSAS Tabular on Azure?

Tags: sql, azure, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, azure-sql-database

I'm attempting to deploy an ssas tabular model (I don't know what I'm doing )

I have made multidimensional on SQL Server 2008 R2 with VS2013. I wanted to try Tabular in conjunction with power BI.

So I set up a SQL Azure DB, I have Azure SQL database and Visual Studio 2013 Pro

I can get the connection to the Azure DB in VS2013 and write T-SQL against it but when I try and create a tabular model and select the Azure database as the SQL Server workspace it fails to make a connection.

Is it something to do with the compatibility module or do I need to create a Azure VM? Thank you for your help ... p.s. this is my fist question ever I'm excited

Comment: What error are you getting when the connection fails?

Comment: Cannot connect to server "XXXXXX.Database.windows.net' reason: an error occurred while connecting to the server.

Comment: Check out sys.event_log https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn270018(v=sql.120).aspx you should get a bit more error information.

Comment: The log file is just full of a bunch of successful logins'

Comment: @NebNerlo did you succeed on the approach suggested by Greg?

Comment: well kinda I started down that path and can confirm after some work we got it running, but eventually just decided to migrate the data to another server which was running SQL 2012 and deployed it there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Azure SQL DB is a relational SQL database. It is not Analysis Services. You can't deploy an Analysis Services database to Azure SQL DB. You will need to create a virtual machine in Azure from a SQL Server Enterprise Edition image and install a Tabular instance and open ports and deploy your tabular model to that VM.

**Update as of October 2016**: They just announced [Azure Analysis Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/analysis-services/). While it is completely separate from Azure SQL Database, it does provide a PaaS offering for Analysis Services tabular models which means you don't have to deploy a VM for this functionality. Currently it supports 1200 and above compatibility level tabular models, not multidimensional models.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I kinda thought that, in that i stated "do I need to create a Azure VM? " thanks for confirming. Ill make an attempt at the VM

Answer (score 2):

Analysis Services is now available as a service that can be provisioned directly inside the Azure Portal (no VM needed):

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/analysis-services-overview/

Comment: Nice! You beat me to it. I just noticed your post after I updated my answer above. Thanks!