# Install "Analysis Services" on Azure SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssas, hybrid, azure-sql-server

**To start off:** 
I know that there is SQL Server Analysis Services and Azure Analysis Services and they are separate products.

**And I know that:** 
On On-Premise installations I can install the "SQL Server Analysis Services" component on my On-Premise SQL Server on my local server. And it will analyse data from this server.

**But can anybody answer this:** 
Is it possible to install the "SQL Server Analysis Services" component on my SQL Server in Azure? I don't mean using "Azure Analysis Services", I want to use the "standard" SQL analysis services like I did with my local SQL Server before, and the only difference is that the SQL Server is now in Azure. So is it possible?

If possible, how to do it, and are there any limitations?

If not possible, is it possible to do anything similar?

If the only way is to host a VM in Azure and install the SQL Server on that VM & install Analysis Services on it, then it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Not possible: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31167945/5070440

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought too.